# dataTransfer setData not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, drag-and-drop, data-transfer

I'm trying to setData type during a dragstart event with key 'application/x-moz-file-promise' on firefox but it fails.

```
evt.dataTransfer.setData('application/x-moz-file-promise', '')
```

Is this some kind of a bug?

Comment: What kind of error does occur?  anything in console?

Comment: It says:    Error: The operation is insecure.